# How to find the common value between records in SQL?

Tags: sql

Just a little question, if I had a database that was using SQL:

```
Names: Max¦ John¦ May¦ Olivia

Numbers: 3, 7, 9¦ 1, 3, 4¦ 8, 5, 3¦ 5, 7, 1
```

Is there a way using SQL to check the "Numbers" column to see how many people like the number 5 and then show their name, who like the number, to the user.

Comment: *Never* store lists of numbers as comma-delimited strings.  It is so wrong to store data that way.  Fix your database.

Comment: Yes, there is.  To get a more detailed answer, you will need to edit your question and provide the relationship between Names and Numbers and which people like which numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first you have a bad database design, but if you still want to move on it here is how to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE Numbers LIKE '%5%';
```

Result:

```
+--------+---------+
|  Name  | Numbers |
+--------+---------+
| May    | 8, 5, 3 |
| Olivia | 5, 7, 1 |
+--------+---------+
```

But I recommand to change that design to somthing like:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(30) );
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE ( Name INT, Number INT);

INSERT INTO @Names VALUES
('Max'),
('John'),
('May'),
('Olivia');
INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES
(1, 3),
(1, 7),
(1, 9),
(2, 1),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 8),
(3, 5),
(3, 3),
(4, 5),
(4, 7),
(4, 1);
/**/
SELECT N.Name, NM.Number
FROM @Names N INNER JOIN @Numbers NM ON N.ID = NM.Name
WHERE NM.Number = 5;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Name  | Number |
+--------+--------+
| May    |      5 |
| Olivia |      5 |
+--------+--------+
```

**[Demo1](http://rextester.com/OBBK22783)**

**[Demo2](http://rextester.com/TQKA6459)**

Here is also a good **[article](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)** to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reasons not to store numbers in a string:

- SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*, not a string.
- SQL has (relatively) lousy string processing capabilities.
- Queries using filters on strings generally cannot make use of indexes.
- Numbers should be stored in the appropriate data type -- which is a number, not a string.
- If the numbers are ids in another table, then you cannot declare foreign key relationships.

If you want to just find "5" in a string, you can use `like`:

```
where numbers like '%5%'
```

This probably doesn't do what you want, because it will match "5" to "15".  Although this can be fixed, go back and understand why you should not be storing data this way.  Instead, you want a table like:

```
Name    Number
Max        3
Max        7
Max        9
John       1
. . .
```

Comment: So this is the database:

Name:   Number
Max:      3, 7, 9
John:     1, 3, 4
May:      8, 5, 3
Olivia:    5, 7, 1

What I need to know is how do you find the common number between the records? I am sorry if I did not make that clear before.